# How does PKG-CONFIG select between two .pc files?

Tags: gcc, pkg-config

I have two .pc files for glib-2.0

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/glib-2.0.pc
/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/glib-2.0.pc
```

They differ with where they point the location of include files.

```
/usr/lib/x86... points to /usr/include
/usr/local/lib... points to /usr/local/include
```

This causes a problem when I run:

```
pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0
```

this returns the following glib-2.0 search locations:

```
-I/usr/local/include/glib-2.0 
-I/usr/local/lib/glib-2.0/include
```

whereas my package manager has installed the glib libraries to

```
/usr/include/glib
```

Question 1: Why is the PKG-CONFIG selecting the second location compared to the first? How can I change this?

Question 2: Is it abnormal to have two of the same .pc files?

Question 3: If I do want to delete one of the .pc files, can I do so safely?

Note:

1. I do not wish to copy over the glib library to /local/ as the package manager will loose sight of this.
2. I do not wish to add -I/usr/include in addition when running gcc as I expect PKG-CONFIG to work properly. (I also think this will cause other problems which I will have to manually modify)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR environment variable to override the default search directory.

There's also PKG_CONFIG_PATH that can be used as a colon-separated list of directories to search for .pc files.

See pkg-config's manual page for more info.

Comment: Thank you, changing PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR to control the default search allows me to select the.pc file that I want.

Comment: Is it not possible to use `PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR` with multiple directories? I have some packages in the cross-compiler root and some in `/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig`, but I'm wanting to avoid conflicts with any of the packages in `/usr/lib/pkgconfig`.